# Datatables ExportOptions switch last two cells

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a DT table that contain 2 dynamic values I change via ajax, hence I need to execute some code for the new value to show on exporting to PDF or EXCEL etc.

In 1 cell, I have a `select` element. In the other cell, I have a changing value depending on the first cell.

I use ExportOptions from DT so I can remove the select values from printing, and also so I can get the updated value from the other cell.

The problem: when I export, the cells I modify with ExportOptions switch, so if I have a 2 row table, the 2 first cells switch with the ones below.

My DT setup is this:

```
  var table = $('.broker-data-table').DataTable({
                "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                dom: 'Bfrtlp',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        exportOptions : {
                            format: {
                                body: exportModify
                            }
                        },
                        orientation: 'landscape',
                        title: 'Investors Payment Information'
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'csvHtml5',
                        exportOptions : {
                            format: {
                                body: exportModify
                            }
                        },
                        title: 'Investors Payment Information'
                    }
                ]
            });
```

The exportModify function:

```
function exportModify(data, row, col, node){
    if (col == 6) {

        return table
            .cell({row: row, column: col})
            .nodes()
            .to$()
            .children('span').text();

    } else if(col == 7) {

        return table
            .cell({row: row, column: col})
            .nodes()
            .to$()
            .text();

    } else {
        return data;
    }
}
```

And this is my table:

```
<table>
   <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Beneficiary</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Bank Entity</th>
            <th>Bank Account</th>
            <th>Account Type</th>
            <th>Routing / Swift</th>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
        <?php foreach($data as $d): ?>
            <tr id="inv-<?= $d['id'] ?>">
                <td><?= $d['beneficiary'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $d['email'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $d['bank_entity'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $d['bank_account'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $d['account_type'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $d['routing_number'] ?></td>
                <td class="month-wraper" id="<?= $d['id'] ?>">
                    <span class="month-changer"><?= $d['payment_month'] ?></span>

                    <select class="month-select" id="<?= $d['id'] ?>">
                        <?php foreach($months_active as $m): ?>
                            <option value="<?= $m ?>"><?= $m ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="payment-amount-td" id="<?= $d['id'] ?>"><?= $d['payment_amount'] ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

This is how the table looks (notice last two columns):

[image]

This is how the table looks exported (see how they switched):

[image]

Comment: Maybe try with `"order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],`

Comment: @Hackerman whoa...i want to cry. whats the reasoning? Its working....

Comment: Yeah, it's because the original line is something like `order by Beneficiary desc`

Comment: Yes for sure, but the cells I'm editing should follow this sorting then... ??